# In Crystal Report line break when used commas

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 3 fields: {Marks1},{Marks2},{Marks3}. I want to line break when commas show.

Marks No.1 data  `( ORD00215855_01,ITEM NO. 293921,TC ID T066725,)`
Marks No.2 data  `(c,ITEM NO. 293922,TC ID T066727,)`
Marks No.3 data  `(ORD00214587_01,ITEM NO. 264876,TC ID T080812,)`

like show:

```
ORD00215855_01
ITEM NO. 293921
TC ID T066725
TC ID T066725
TC ID T066727
ORD00214587_01
ITEM NO. 264876
TC ID T080812
```

Please help me.

Comment: please show us what have you tried so far. also go through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I used this function but line is not break ,if (isnull({Table.MARKSNO3})) then {Table.MARKSNO1}else {Table.MARKSNO1}+ chr(13) + chr(10) +{Table.MARKSNO2}+ chr(13) + chr(10) +{Table.MARKSNO3}

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Replace({Table.MARKSNO1},",",Chr(10) + Chr(13))
```

to replace the comma.